# Unable to assign value to page item from bar chart for inline popup

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I've created a bar chart and dynamic action for inline pop up (classic report). When I click each bar popup box is coming up but its not giving the output from database.

[image: Inline Popup with no data]

steps used -

1. Created  **region1** , chart and series (for bar chart).
2. Created **region2** , created classic report and made it as inline popup (for popup)
   Using the below query in **Region2**
   `select pws , prdct_cd  from pws_data where pws = :PWS` (If I send :PWS as 'PWS3' it will give 2 rows) refer below image
3. Created a dynamic action for **region1**
   1.Event created
   When : Click
   Selection type : region
   Region : **Region1**
   2.Action Created
   Action : Open Region
   Selection Type : region
   Region : **Region2**
   4.Created Page Item : PWS for **Region1**

How do assign value

I'm unable to the pass values (PWS1 or PWS2 ..) to my Page Item (PWS).

I'm noobie in Apex. Kindly Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this, based on the sample data set EMP/DEPT. The functionality of the page is that you have a bar chart with the employee count per department. When you click on a department, you get a report listing all the employees for that department. The report is of type "inline dialog".

1. Create chart (bar chart) with following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
  d.dname,
  d.deptno,
  COUNT(e.empno)
  FROM
       dept d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e ON d.deptno = e.deptno
 GROUP BY
  d.dname,
  d.deptno
```

Label = DNAME, Value = COUNT(e.empno).

2. Create a hidden page item P1_DEPTNO in the chart region.
3. Create a report (region name "Emp Report") in position "inline dialogs" with region template "inline popup". Table name: `EMP`, Where clause: `deptno = :P1_DEPTNO`, Page Items to Submit: `P1_DEPTNO`
4. Create a Dynamic Action on change of P1_DEPTNO with 2 true actions: (1) Refresh region "Emp Report" and (2) Open Region "Emp Report". You need to refresh first to submit the value of P1_DEPTNO to the session so you only get the rows you need.
5. Add a link to your chart of type "Redirect to URL" with the following javascript code:

```
javascript:apex.item( "P1_DEPTNO" ).setValue( '#DEPTNO#' );
```

That should be all. This worked for me, I suggest you try it with EMP/DEPT first and then convert to your own page. Tested on 20.2 but should work on 19.1 as well.

Comment: Perfecto ! I was missing the JavaScript part. Thanks Much.